# Spyder doesnt recognize any installed packages, so doesnt load them

Tags: python, spyder

I have been dealing with this problem for months and still found no solution.

I installed anacond first, and then installed spyder (but not from anaconda interface, but from outside it). I want to use spyder but when I open cmd terminal and type "pip install pyarrow", the cmd shows it is already installed but spyder doesnt load it.

Thank you very much/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Spyder is running a python interpreter version (say 3.7), but the pyarrow package was only installed for a later version (say 3.8).

Try this:

1. Check your Python interpreter version
2. Check for which versions of Python was Pyarrow package installed.

Spyder runs a python interpreter by default and you can change which version to run:
Go to Spyder --> Preferences --> Python interpreter --> Use the following python interpreter (insert the path of the desired python version).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the asnwer! I had already tried that, but still doesnt work. What I want is to choose a certain python version and install the packages in there. For example, I read something out there that says I have to type in the CMD: 

" <path of the python version> -m pip install <package> "

I tried that out also but didnt work neither. I am planning to unistall everything, but that would be my las resort.

Thank you!